# Prove that $\cot^n\frac{\alpha}{2}+ \cot^n\frac{\beta}{2}+ \cot^n\frac{\gamma}{2}\ge3^\frac{n+2}{2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Let $\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\gamma$ angles of some triangle and n natural number,
Prove that

> $$\cot^n\frac{\alpha}{2}+ \cot^n\frac{\beta}{2}+ \cot^n\frac{\gamma}{2}\ge3^\frac{n+2}{2}$$

I've tried something and get
$$\cot^n\frac{\alpha}{2}+ \cot^n\frac{\beta}{2}+ \tan^n\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$$

but n is problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use Jensen's inequality for $f(x) = \cot x$ and the fact that $a^n+b^n+c^n\geq\dfrac{(a+b+c)^n}{3^{n-1}}$

Comment: Jensen for $\cot^n x$ would work too.  +1

Comment: @Macavity yeah, I just realized that

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you attack this geometrically.  Construct triangle ABC.  Bisect the angles, and the angle bisectors meet at the center of the "incircle"
$\cot \alpha/2 + \cot \beta/2+ \cot \gamma/2$ = (1/2) perimeter of the triangle / radius of the incircle.  This cannot be less than $3 \sqrt3$.